# Scikit-learn χ² (chi-squared) statistic and corresponding contingency table

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, statistics, scikit-learn

In the docs for the chi-squared univariate feature selection function of scikit-learn http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_selection.chi2.html, it states

> This score can be used to select the n_features features with the highest values for the χ² (chi-square) statistic from X, which must contain booleans or **frequencies** (e.g., term counts in document classification), relative to the classes.

I am struggling to understand what the corresponding contingency table would look like, especially in the case of frequency features.

For example, consider the below dataset with boolean features and targets:

```
import numpy as np

>>> X = np.random.randint(2, size=50).reshape(10, 5)
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])

>>> y = np.random.randint(2, size=10)
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
```

To construct the contingency table with respect to the first feature, we can do this (excuse my PEP8 violation)

```
import scipy as sp

>>> contingency_table = sp.sparse.coo_matrix(
...    (np.ones_like(y), (X[:, 0], y)), 
...    shape=(np.unique(X[:, 0]).shape[0], np.unique(y).shape[0])).A
array([[1, 2],
       [3, 4]])
```

So now I can calculate the chi-squared statistic and its p-values

```
>>> sp.stats.chi2_contingency(contingency_table)
(0.17857142857142855,
 0.67260381744151676,
 1,
 array([[ 1.2,  1.8],
       [ 2.8,  4.2]]))
```

And this ought to be consistent with scikit-learn's `chi2`

```
from sklearn.feature_selection import chi2

>>> chi2_, pval = chi2(X, y)
>>> chi2_[0], pval[0]
(0.023809523809523787, 0.87737055606414338)
```

...Nope. Have I misinterpreted something?

Also, what does the contingency table look like in the case of frequencies? I assumed it would be something like

```
contingency_table = sp.sparse.coo_matrix(
    (np.ones_like(y), (X[:, 0], y)), 
    shape=(X[:, 0].max()+1, np.unique(y).shape[0])).A
```

But the corresponding table of expected frequencies will most likely have several zero elements.

**Edit:**

To clarify further, consider the first feature `X[:, 0]` that is, say, *gender* and the targets `y`, say, *handedness*.

From this we get the cross tabulation

```
                Right-handed    Left-handed (!right-handed)
Male            1               2
Female (!male)  3               4
```

And we can assess the significance of the difference between the two proportions using the Chi-squared test by setting the expected frequency

[image: expfreq]

`sklearn.feature_selection.chi2` does this directly without resorting to explicitly computing the table and obtains the scores using a more efficient procedure that is equivalent to `scipy.stats.chisquare`.

After explicitly enumerating the table shown above, I wanted to verify it is consistent with `chi2` when applying `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency` and to my dismay, it isn't. I'd like to ask why it isn't.

Comment: Interesting: I've been trying to solve a very similar problem in the last hour, but from the opposite direction: from the first example contingency table found in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VskmMgXmkMQ, verify that the corresponding 2d boolean dataset (X=is_male, y=is_deposit) fed to `sklearn.feature_selection.chi2` should yield the same result, and trying to understanding why it's not the case, by studying the source..

Comment: I find it confusing that you begin by stating a dataset of 5 features, and then build the remaining of your case using only the first feature. I think that's what makes @larsmans's answer confusing in this context, because he is answering a different question.

Comment: this is pretty cool. it looks like the contingency matrix is a 2x2 matrix and you get a single p-val for the set of all the features in producing the target, whereas the feature_selection chi2 shows the p-vals for each feature independently of the others in producing the target

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Consider a column `x` of `X`.  `sklearn.feature_selection.chi2` tests whether
the frequencies of the `y` values where `x` is 1 agree with the frequencies of `y` in
the full population.  (@larsman's answer shows how you can reproduce the calculation with numpy and scipy.)  This is not the same as the standard 2x2 contingency table
analysis of `x` and `y`.  In a 2x2 contingency table analysis, the frequencies of `y`
where `x` is 0 also contribute to the test.

Suppose we form the contingency table for `x` and `y`:

```
    | y=0  y=1
----+---------
x=0 |  a    b
x=1 |  c    d
```

Let n = a + b + c + d.  This is the number of samples (i.e. same as len(x) and len(y)).

Let nx = c + d.  This is the number of occurrences of `1` in `x`.

Let py1 = (b + d)/n.  This is the fraction of the full population where y is 1.

`sklearn.feature_selection.chi2` performs a chi2 test on [c, d] using the expected
values [(1-py1)*nx, py1*nx].  This is not the same as the standard contingency table
analysis of a 2x2 table.

Here's an extreme example.  Suppose the 2x2 contingency table for `x` and `y` is

```
    |  y=0  y=1
----+----------
x=0 |   8    8
x=1 |  20  188
```

The sklearn calculation produces a chi2 score of 1.58, with a p-value of 0.208.

The contingency table analysis of `scipy.stats.chi2_contingency` gives a chi2 score of 18.6, with a p-value of 1.60e-5.

Comment: _This is not the same as the standard contingency table analysis of a 2x2 table._
This is the essence of my question; is this not intended to be a standard contingency table analysis? And if not, what exactly is it supposed to be (link to article/paper?) I think this ought to be made clear in the documentation.

Answer (score 6):

Given your data,

```
>>> X = array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
...        [1, 1, 0, 1, 1],
...        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
...        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
...        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
...        [1, 0, 0, 0, 1],
...        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
...        [0, 1, 1, 0, 0],
...        [1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
...        [1, 1, 1, 1, 0]])
>>> y = array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
```

this is what `feature_selection.chi2` computes:

```
>>> Y = np.vstack([1 - y, y])
>>> observed = np.dot(Y, X)
>>> observed
array([[3, 1, 1, 2, 2],
       [4, 2, 3, 2, 4]])
```

These are the observed feature frequencies, per class, i.e. the contingency table. Then the expected values:

```
>>> feature_count = X.sum(axis=0)
>>> class_prob = Y.mean(axis=1)
>>> expected = np.dot(feature_count.reshape(-1, 1), class_prob.reshape(1, -1)).T
>>> expected
array([[ 2.8,  1.2,  1.6,  1.6,  2.4],
       [ 4.2,  1.8,  2.4,  2.4,  3.6]])
```

Finally, it runs a χ² test:

```
>>> from scipy.stats import chisquare
>>> score, pval = chisquare(observed, expected)
>>> score
array([ 0.02380952,  0.05555556,  0.375     ,  0.16666667,  0.11111111])
>>> pval
array([ 0.87737056,  0.81366372,  0.54029137,  0.6830914 ,  0.73888268])
```

The scores are the relevant bit: they're used to sort the features by discriminative power. Note that you get one score and one *p*-value **per feature**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I don't think I've done a great job at asking this question and as a result, we may not be on the same page. What you've said is clear from the source code (a more efficient but less readable variant) and in the docs. What I am after is an “R x C table”  s.t. [chi2_contingency](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.chi2_contingency.html) would yield the same result as `sklearn.feature_selection.chi2`.

Comment: The example you have shown can be construed as a decomposition of such a table into arrays to be passed to `scipy.stats.chisquare` which would yield the same results. However, I am interested in obtaining the original R x C table.

Comment: @larsmans: For standard contingency table analysis, your `expected` array is not correct.  The array of expected frequencies must have the same marginal sums (i.e. row and column sums) as the array of observed frequencies.

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser The `chisquare` docstring suggests otherwise, are you saying it's wrong?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser Also note that we're not doing a single chi2 test on a contingency table, but one test per feature, where a feature value `X[i,j]` is the count of event `j` in sample `X[i]` (and a sample is a drawn from a multinomial).

Comment: Sorry, I should have written a longer comment (or no comment at all!).  Your `expected` is correct for the calculation that is done by `sklearn.feature_selection.chi2`.  As you stated, it is not doing a single chi2 test on the `observed` contingency table (which is the test I was thinking of when I said it was not correct for "standard contingency table analysis").  It is also not doing 2x2 contingency table analysis per column.  I think the latter point is the essence of @tiao's question.